# How to convert a JavaScript regex into Java?

Tags: java, javascript, android, regex

I have been using this regex to validate YouTube links using JavaScript:

```
function is_valid_video(url) {
        var p = /^(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/;
        return (url.match(p)) ? RegExp.$1 : false;
    }
```

Since I'm learning to develop Android apps, I want to convert this function to use it in Java.

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that.

Comment: I recommend using a standard url parsing library. Unless your parameters are always in the same order (which I see isn't the case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static bool is_valid_video(String url) {
return url.matches("Your Regex Goes Here");
}
```

Read [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) for more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;    

private static final String myRegexp = "/^(?:http?:\/\/)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/";
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(myRegexp );

public boolean isValid(String url){
    //This is what String.matches() does internally but now you have already crated the pattern instance -> more efficient
    Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
    return m.matches();
}
```

You might have to do some character escaping in the regExp String. See [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class.

On a side note: Using regexp to validate a link of this complexity is not a good idea. You will run into issues with upkeep and sustainability.

Comment: Your `String myRegexp` doesn't compile.

Comment: Please read the comment. It clearly states that you will have to do some escaping to get it to compile in Java.

Comment: Well, that comment should be clear from the beginning and before posting the code.